# Can't Subscript from swift extension

Tags: arrays, swift, uint8array

This is the problem:

```
typealias Byte = UInt8

protocol ByteProtocol {}
extension UInt8: ByteProtocol {}

extension Array where Element: ByteProtocol  {

    subscript (index: Int) -> UInt8 {
        return self[Int(index % self.count)]
    }

}
```

This gives me Overflow even if it is mathematically impossible:

```
var p: [Byte] = [Byte]()
p.append(15)
print(p[10])
```

So what is the mistake here? P.S. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: That `Int` initializer call is  redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't overload subscripts this way. Even if you could, you'd be creating an infinite loop in your implementation. Your implementation also would be illegal, since it returns something other than `Element`.

What you mean is something like this:

```
extension Array where Element: ByteProtocol  {

    subscript (wrapping index: Int) -> Element {
        return self[Int(index % self.count)]
    }
}

var p: [Byte] = [Byte]()
p.append(15)
print(p[wrapping: 10])
```

Comment: And *then* it could be an unrestricted extension (the where-clause could be a consequence of OP's previous question). – Minor remark: `self[index % self.count]` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't give you an "overflow". It gives you an out-of-range error. There is no element index 10 in an array with only 1 element. The crash occurs before your `subscript` implementation is ever called (as you could easily discover by breakpointing it). You cannot magically change the meaning of an existing `subscript` implementation in the way you are hoping to.

Comment: Look at the implementation of his subscript.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov It is never called. He could easily have discovered this by putting a breakpoint on it.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that.

Comment: @matt That's probably the crucial part you should add to your answer :)

Comment: @sulthan Okay, did so. But it seems so obvious!

Comment: @matt I agree it's not a difficult issue, but if OP understood that, do you think he'd be posting this question?

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of subscript is called, not yours. Hence, it's trying to actually access the 10th element, which doesn't exist.

You can't override the behaviour of a struct like `Array` using an extension. They're not polymorphic. You can, however, add a new definition of a subscript, as rob showed.